# error "Access to the path 'MiPathLocal' is denied." al descargar un fichero FTP a Local c#

Tags: c#, ftp

Tengo que descargar un fichero de un servidor FTP a Local, pero me aparece este error:

> ```
> "Access to the path 'Path Local donde quiero descargarlo' is denied.".
> ```

Mi código es este:

```
public static bool FtpDownloadFile(string username, string password, string localFileFullPath, string remoteUriPath)
        {
            FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(remoteUriPath);
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = null;
            StreamReader reader = null;
            StreamWriter writer = null;
            try
            {
                stream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
                reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                writer = new StreamWriter(localFileFullPath, false);
                writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
                return true;
            }
            finally
            {
                stream.Close();
                reader.Close();
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: El error es bastante claro: el sistema ha denegado el acceso a la ruta especificada. Esto suele indicar que el usuario con el que se ejecuta la aplicación no tiene permisos para acceder o realizar la operación solicitada sobre la carpeta.

Comment: le paso las credenciales de mi usuario, que sí tiene acceso, en otras funciones en las que necesito también acceso me ha funcionado sin problema @AsierVillanueva

Comment: Dependiendo de la ruta puede que no tengas permisos. existen varias "rutas especiales" a las que te recomiendo no tener como carpeta FTP tales como las que están definidas en el [Enumeración Environment.SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)

Comment: no coincide con ninguna de las listadas @SergioParraGuerra

Comment: Como dice @Asier Villanueva revisa los permisos de dicha carpeta. Tu código está en una aplicación ASP.NET? Si es así, establece permisos para la cuenta de Application Pool